# Cannot open Eclipse IDE, Eclipse not launching after initial launch

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having trouble running eclipse, I was able to start and run the program after the initial download but after making some tutorial programs and closing it I am unable to open it again. I can open it if I uninstall it and redownload it, but everytime I close out of it and try to reopen it, it pops up with the loading screen.

I want to open eclipse IDE without encountering the above error.I have installed and reinstalled the IDE as well as the JDK but still cannot fix it.

Comment: You probably want to let us know what OS you're on. Regardless, try starting Eclipse from the command line, adding the `-consoleLog` option, which will give you some insight as to what's going on. If you're lazy, you can try with just the `-clean` option, in case you have some cached data that is interfering with launch, since you've been able to launch successfully in the past.

Comment: What version of Eclipse? Recent versions include a JDK so no longer a requirement to also install JDK. In any case, which JDK version did you install? After installing Eclipse, do you configure your workspace via Windows > Preferences ? Did you try creating a new workspace?